# Locally nilpotent derivations closed under isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra

I have been struggling to prove or find a counterexample to the following:

Fix a field $k$ of characteristic $0$. Let $R:= k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $A$ be the ring of differential operators on $R$ (so $A$ is isomorphic to the $n$th Weyl algebra; in particular, it is just a ring of polynomials in the operators $\hat{x_1}, ..., \hat{x_n}, \partial_1,...,\partial_n$, where $\hat{x_i}$ is the multiplication by $x_i$ operator and $\partial_i$ is the ith partial derivative operator). We say an operator $D \in A$ is locally nilpotent if for all $f \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ there exists a positive integer $n$ so that $D^n(f) = 0$. Let $\phi: A \to A$ be an automorphism of $A$. If $D$ is a locally nilpotent $k$-derivation in $A$, is the same true of $\phi(D)$? If this is true, does the statement hold in general when $R$ is a finitely generated integral domain over $k$?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true - in fact, automorphisms of $A$ need not even send derivations to derivations. Let $n=1$ so that the Weyl algebra is $k\langle x,\partial\rangle/(\partial x- x\partial=1)$. Then $\partial$ is locally nilpotent: if $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, $\partial^{n+1}p=0$, while $x$ acts injectively on $k[x]$. But there is an automorphism sending $\partial\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto -\partial$.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked this case in posing the question, and had in mind the case that a given derivation in $A$ is the image of a derivation in $A$ under an automorphism. Maybe there is a simple counterexample in this setting as well?

Comment: @user450138 If there is a simple counterexample, I don't see it right now. I'm even a little unsure about what the conditions one would need to place on $\phi$ to get that $\phi(D)$ is a derivation - the classification of automorphisms might be the next place to look (Dixmier, 1960s, I think?) to see what one of these things has to do.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer as it was my fault for not phrasing the question correctly. I had the following particular family of automorphisms in mind: let $m <n$ be a positive integer and for $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, if $i \leq m$ $f_i$ be a polynomial in the variables $x_{m+1},...,x_n$ and otherwise set $f_i = 0$. The automorphisms I had in mind are given by $x_i \mapsto x_i +f_i$ and $\partial_i\mapsto\partial_i-\sum_{k=1}^n \partial f_k/\partial x_i \cdot \partial_k$. Local nilpotence for derivations is seemingly preserved (in general, I don't understand the automorphism group of $A_n$).

Comment: I'm sorry that this question did not lead to a better answer. For what it's worth, I don't really understand the whole automorphism group either.